# Postgres cannot open CSV file for read access: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file located on a postgres 8.4 server filesystem:

```
COPY ip2location_db1 FROM '/pgsrc/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB9.CSV' WITH CSV QUOTE AS '"';
```

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot open file for read access: Permission denied
```

The file has owner `postgres` and I tried putting it on `/var/lib/pgsql` and also on `/pgsources` folder, to which I gave ownership to `postgres` user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try running postgres using `sudo su`?  Maybe the problem is with the permissions which Postgres itself has (or does not have).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Since Postgres is designed to run as a demon, running it under a root shell (`sudo su`) is probably not enough to change what permissions it runs under.

Comment: "Execution of Postgres server is not allowed as user root. The server must be started as a non-priviledged user"

Comment: Anyway, I have also tried to chmod 777 both the file and the `pgsources` folder it's in. Still no luck.

Comment: Perhaps try sticking the file in /tmp or some other folder where the entire path is readable by all users. From there you can verify that it truly is a file permission issue.

Comment: already tried that. Didn't work :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this issue before, and rather than jockey around with permissions all the time, I just import from STDIN.

This would accomplish what you want (albeit not precisely the way you want to do it), but I think it's a lot less cumbersome and error-prone. Try:

```
cat /pgsrc/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB9.CSV | psql -c "COPY ip2location_db1 FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV);"
```

This does imply that you're running the query from a shell script or something, but to implement it the other way, you'd have to incorporate the change of permissions with a shell script or something.

(Also, according to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), the default quote is the double quote, so you don't need to specify the quote.)