# Insert a textfile PostgreSQL through ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a database and a table.

Table Name( A, B, C)

I also have a text file that is formatted like:

numA1:numB1

numA2:numB2

...

numAn:numBn

How do I insert this text file into the table and set all row for column C to a value? The value for Column C should be the same throughout the table.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

```
\copy your_table(c) FROM 'yourPathOnClient/yourFile.txt';
```

Comment: and then after copy, do an update on column c to your value where column c is null.

Comment: But what if I want to add another text file into the same table, but I want different c?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a table that matches the file you are importing:

```
CREATE TABLE csv_data (
    colA FLOAT,
    colB FLOAT
);
```

Step 2: From the shell, copy your data into the table using STDIN. (See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35336969/1477364) if you're curious why STDIN is the way to go.)

```
cat YourFile.csv | psql -c "COPY csv_data FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ':', HEADER FALSE);"
```

Step 3: Add the column that's not in the data file, and give it a default value.

```
ALTER TABLE csv_data ADD COLUMN colC FLOAT DEFAULT 1234.56;
```

**Edit:**

If you want to import more than one file:

Step 1: Create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE csv_data_staging (
    colA FLOAT,
    colB FLOAT
);

CREATE TABLE csv_data (
    colA FLOAT,
    colB FLOAT,
    colC FLOAT
);
```

Step 2:

```
cat YourFile.csv | psql -c "COPY csv_data_staging FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ':', HEADER FALSE);"
```

Step 3:

```
INSERT INTO csv_data SELECT *, 1234.45 /* The C Value */ FROM csv_data_staging;
TRUNCATE csv_data_staging;
```

Repeat steps 2 & 3 as needed.

Comment: But what if I want to add another text file into the same table, but I want different c?